# Decimal and Thousands separator in Salesforce Reporting

Tags: reporting

I am exporting data from reports and I am getting comma(,) instead of dot(.) for number columns.

Please tell me what should I do to get dot as seperator.

Answer (score 2):

Change your locale in salesforce.com to an English-using locale, such as UK, US, or Canada (Your Name > Settings/My Settings > Personal Information). Your separators will be based on your locale settings.